# Filter between dates and SUM with LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

In the following query I want to always display the rows even if the SUM result is 0.

Without the WHERE clause it works fine, but when I want to filter between dates, no result is returned. What detail is failing?

```
SELECT tc.cars,
COALESCE(SUM(ts.sales),0) AS cars_sales
FROM tbl_cars tc
LEFT JOIN tbl_sales ts ON tc.id_cars = ts.id_cars
WHERE tc.recDate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND DATE_ADD( '2017-05-01' , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY tc.cars
ORDER BY tc.cars;
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/425e6d/1/0

Comment: You have no cars between April and May. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/425e6d/11

Comment: @chris85, "I want to always display the rows even if the SUM result is 0".

Comment: ... or even if no rows are returned there should be `0`s??

Comment: @chris85, I did. I think what he means is, he wants to *always* display all the cars, even if there were no sales in that period.

Comment: @ishegg I'll await clarification, the `What detail is failing?` had me thinking it was an error.

Comment: This is really a display issue and , as such, this aspect o the problem should really be handled in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the condition on the JOIN instead. Also, I think you mean to `COUNT()` the fields, since `ts.sales` is `VARCHAR` in your schema, and also empty in your sample data.

```
SELECT 
    tc.cars, COALESCE(COUNT(ts.sales), 0) AS cars_sales
FROM
    tbl_cars tc
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_sales ts ON tc.id_cars = ts.id_cars
        AND tc.recDate BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND DATE_ADD('2020-05-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY tc.cars
ORDER BY tc.cars;
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/425e6d/9)

Comment: @ ishegg and Yusuf Thanks. In my query(more complex than my example) I had just started structuring the query as your suggestion and for some reason I did not identify it did not work. Your solution has put me on the right path. My query has several LEFT JOIN and my AND...BETWEEN clause was in the wrong JOIN. Now it works fine.Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
SELECT tc.cars,
COALESCE(SUM(ts.sales),0) AS cars_sales
FROM tbl_cars tc
LEFT JOIN tbl_sales ts ON tc.id_cars = ts.id_cars
and tc.recDate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND DATE_ADD( '2017-05-01' , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY tc.cars
ORDER BY tc.cars;
```

After your `join` has executed, `where` clause will filter the entire dataset based on the condition provided in where clause. Since your dataset has no entries for the months of April and May, the empty result-set is expected.